# Hyperledger fabric's ChannelCreationPolicy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, policies

I am struggling so hard to write policy for creating channel (ChannelCreationPolicy) here is my configtx.yaml

```
---
Organizations:
- &OrdererOrg
  Name: OrdererOrg
  ID: OrdererMSP
  MSPDir: ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer-org/msp
- &ShopOrg
  Name: ShopOrgMSP
  ID: ShopOrgMSP
  MSPDir: ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/shop-org/msp
  AnchorPeers:
  - Host: shop-peer-0
    Port: 7051


Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: solo
  Addresses:
  - orderer0:7050
  BatchTimeout: 2s
  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
  Organizations:

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:

Profiles:
  TwoOrgGenesis:
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
      - *OrdererOrg
    Consortiums:
      InsuranceConsortium:
        # ChannelCreationPolicy:
        #   Admins:
        #     Type: Signature
        #     Rule: "OR('ShopOrgMSP.admin')"
        Organizations:
        - *ShopOrg
  TwoOrgChannel:
    Consortium: InsuranceConsortium
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
      - *ShopOrg
```

I tried to put ChannelCreationPolicy block above in the commented area but it says : `'Profiles[TwoOrgGenesis].Consortiums[InsuranceConsortium]' has invalid keys: ChannelCreationPolicy`

I can't find place for ChannelCreationPolicy inside that .yaml. So how can I write policy so that, for example, only ShopOrgMSP admins could create channel?

Comment: It's not supported when using configtxgen.  I just opened a feature request:  https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-13192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source for configtxgen](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go), it doesn't look like channel creation policies are supported by the tool. You would need to submit this change as a config update transaction.

Unfortunately, this is a highly non-trivial process, but at least there is an example (for adding an org to a channel) [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/channel_update_tutorial.html).

Comment: I have the same problem. @paul-russell maybe you can provide an example of a configuration that only one Organization can create channels.
I've tried to guess how such configuration should look but had no luck