# channel creation policy restricted to only 1 org

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

if I have 3 orgs in a consortium and I want only one organization to be able to create new channel, how do I restrict other 2 orgs not to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to submit this change as a config update transaction. Please see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658094/hyperledger-fabrics-channelcreationpolicy) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) Only add the org you want to create channels to the consortium definition when you create the genesis block / system channel

2) Set the `ChannelCreationPolicy`.  Unfortunately this cannot be done via configtxgen / configtx.yaml so you will either need to programmatically create the system channel (channel with consortium definition) or you can use configtxgen / configtx.yaml to create the genesis block / system channel and then perform a config update transaction to modify the `ChannelCreationPolicy`

Option 1 is the simplest and then you can follow the links in the samples on how to add orgs to a channel

Comment: Same problem. Could you give an example (json) of such config update transaction? I defined a new policy under the Channel section and used it in `ChannelCreationPolicy` definition, but it doesn't work.